# How to give hover effect on the image used in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I attached 2 images below 1 is simple and other is with hover .I need orange border on hover like the second image .Any 1 knows how to give this type of hover by css

Ny code below :

```
<div class="col-md-4 image-hover img-opacity">   
  <img class="img-1" src="assets/images/img-1.png">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dummy text</p>
</div>
```

[image: simple image]

[image: hover image]

Comment: google is your friend!

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: @pedram Is it possible to give hover on this type of image by css or jquery  ?

Comment: @user3784723 Google is still your friend (clue: yes).

Comment: @user3784723 css -> `img:hover {} ` and jquery -> `$('img').hover(function(){}`

Comment: what hover effect ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
  content:url("assets/images/img-1.png");
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container:hover .image {  
  content:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");
  opacity:2;
}  

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img class="image">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dummy text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working but can i also add background colour with opacity ?

Comment: Ok i will but will you please also let me know how to add background colour in it

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example, note `.hover` ticks with `console.log` but `mouseover` event triggers only one time you hover over the image.

```js
// Jquery
$('.img-1').hover(function() {
    // do stuff
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});

// pure javascript

var img = document.querySelector('.img-1');

img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  // do stuff
  
  //console.log('do stuff');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 image-hover img-opacity">
    <img class="img-1" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dummy text</p>
</div>
```